# Mushroom Identification: Brown gilled mushroom in Ohio lawn near rotting stump roots

Tags: species-identification, mycology

Even though I ID a lot on this site, I'm rather unqualified to ID mushrooms (even with the help of sites like [urbanmushrooms.com](http://urbanmushrooms.com/index.php?id=69)).

**Can anyone help me ID this mushroom species?**

[image: with measurement] [image: in yard]

Attributes:

- **Morphology**: convex cap; gills possibly free, adnexed, or sinuate (I really can't tell!); stem is equal or slightly club-shaped
- **Color**: Brown cap; white gills; white/brown stalk
- **Size**: 1.5-2.5 inches tall; cap 0.25-1 inch diameter
- **Other sensory**: cap texture is smooth/waxy similar to [white button mushroom](https://www.walmart.com/grocery/ip/Whole-White-Mushrooms-16-oz/10451903) one buys in a grocery store; smell is minimal but perhaps slightly musty?
- **Location**: Eastern Ohio (Ohio Valley, about 10 miles West of the Ohio River)
- **Habitat**: growing in recently moist (though almost dry) grass near (but not on) a rotting stump.  Violets, clovers, and other herby weeds also growing in lawn nearby.
- **Timing**: Mid July; found on a sunny day after a week of on-and-off rain

More photos (click to enlarge):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: stump of which mushrooms were growing nearby]

Comment: You will need a spore print ; put a cap on newsprint in an undisturbed location for a day or so. The newsprint gives both a white and black background reference.

Comment: @blacksmith37 already in that process... waiting [not so] patiently

Comment: those mushrooms grow a lot near me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was advised by Walt Sturgeon, author of [Appalachian Mushroom: a Field Guide](https://www.ohioswallow.com/book/Appalachian+Mushrooms) as well as members of [Poisons Help; Emergency Identification For Mushrooms & Plants](https://www.facebook.com/groups/144798092849300/) Facebook group that this is likely [***Marasmiellus luxurians***](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/gymnopus_luxurians.html).

[image]

<sup>Credit: Walt Sturgeon 2018 | Source: [Mushroomobserver.org](https://mushroomobserver.org/image/show_image/891348?obs=322694)</sup>

[Mushroomexpert.org](https://www.mushroomexpert.com/gymnopus_luxurians.html) provides the following supportive pieces of info:

- Ecology matches: "growing gregariously or in tight clusters in woodchips, or on lawns (probably fruiting from dead, buried roots), and, rarely, fruiting directly from logs and stumps; summer and fall."
- Location matches: "widely distributed and relatively common east of the Great Plains".

Walt Sturgeon suggested the following when I asked him about comparing this to similar-looking *Entoloma:*

> Marasmiellus has a white to buff spore print.  Entoloma spores are ruddy pink.  A spore print is made by removing the stem and place the mushroom gill side down on white paper. cover with a bowl. wait several hours and there should be a spore deposit on the paper.

- My spore prints did appear to be white.